# No smooth music during activities switching

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

There are many activities in my app, and I want music to play independently in the background, even while switching activities. Currenly When I switch to another activity, music stops for a while then starts from the beginning.
How to make music play independently in the background?

My code:

```
public class StartMusic extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.musicname);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        //other codes
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        player.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        player.start();
    }


}
```

Then I extend this acivity in another activities:

```
public class OpenerPlay extends StartMusic {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opener_play);

        String uripath = "android.resource://com.example.android.appname/" + R.raw.musicname;

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.id);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uripath);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });

        final Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
        final TextView button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bunton);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                startActivity(intent);
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                    return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    return true;
                }
                return true;

            };

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: use service to start the music.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Service` to play your music. More about `Services` can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Afterwards you can also run your `Service` in a different process, which results into having more memory available, but it depends on your case if that's necessary or not. More about processes can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)